# Read Excel file in python with the same format as the Excel file

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I would like to read an Excel file in Python, with the data in the exact same format as the Excel file.

I have an Excel file with some columns with an int format i.e 2,000. Others with float format, i.e 1,999.52. And another column with dates in "long format", i.e 12-31-2020 is written as Thursday, 31st of December 2020.

Given that this Excel file has some formulas in it, my code is:

```
excel = load_workbook('excelfileroute', data_only=True)
```

Is there a way to import all the data from an Excel file as strings, with the data format unchanged? Or a way I could import the data maintaining the format in the Excel file?

Thanks

Comment: This is only possible if you write your own interpreter for Excel's numbr formats.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to do what you want is to read the data normally, then save it back to the original data type at the end.